# Disable links during drag events Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag

I'm having issues handeling some drag events... What I'm working on is a draggable control panel, and I want to disable click events during the drag. Is there a way to globally disable click events during the drag? Another issue I've found is that when someone starts the drag over a link or image the you get a psuedo-element drag of the image/link and then the control panel is stuck to the mouse because the original drag event got eat up somewhere.

any help or direction would be nice.

this is what i'm working with

```
  dragElement.mousedown(function(event) {
    sticker.css('cursor', 'move');
    if ((event.button == 1 && window.event != null) || event.button == 0) {
      //second catch here in case user stops drag and re-initiates drag
      //without moving away from sticker
      document.onselectstart = function() {
        return false;
      };
      startDrag(event);
    }
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    handleDrag(event);
  });

  dragElement.mouseup(function() {
    endDrag();
    $(document).unbind('mousemove', handleDrag);
  });
```

Comment: did you get this to work ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the link or image elements, try to prevent their default behavior by original JavaScript

```
event.preventDefault(); //standard browser
```

or

```
event.returnValue=true; //IE
```

or just a function in jQuery for both

```
event.preventDefault();
```